# How to change entry values for only certain variables to NA

Tags: r, dplyr, data-management

Suppose I have 8 variables named `MED1` to `MED8` in a dataset called *2007d*. I want to create a new variable called `Totalmeds` which will be the sum of all 8 variables in case an entry is present in a certain row. The variables `MED1` to `MED8` also contains `-9` as an entry which is to be treated as null and not counted towards the total for the 8 variables.

For example, if `MED 1= 2368`, `MED 2= 2344`, `MED3=-9`, `MED4=2145`, `MED5=-9`, `MED6=-9`, `MED7=8765`, and `MED8=2345` for a certain row, then I want the `total` column to show `5` as the output, i.e, not considering -9 as an entry for the total.

I tried individually replacing each column with `NA`

```r
library{dplyr}
`2007d` <- 
  `2007d` %>%
   replace_with_na(replace = list(MED1 = c(-9.00)))
```

but since I have multiple columns was wondering if there is a more efficient way.

I also tried using the mutate_at function:

```r
`2007d` <- 
  `2007d` %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("MED")), na_if, y = -9)
```

but it is not working.

The initial rows of the 8 columns in the dataset looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64ctO.png)

I wanted to know if there is an efficient method to change just those variables in the whole dataset so that I do not have to individually make modifications to each variable and then calculate total

Comment: Could you edit your question to include reproducible sample data?

Comment: E.g. `2007d = data.frame(MED1 = 1)` is not valid R code. How do you manage to name a `data.frame` like so?  *back-ticking* 2007d?

Comment: Thank you so much. My apologies. have added how the initial rows of the data columns looks like

Comment: Include data as text. Use `dput(head(your_data))` to do so.

Answer (score 2):

> For example- if MED 1= 2368, MED 2= 2344, MED3=-9, MED4=2145, MED5=-9, MED6=-9, MED7=8765 and MED8=2345 for a certain row, then I want the total column to show 5 as the output

Probably, you are looking for `rowSums` with condition `> 0`:

```r
> df = structure(list(MED1 = c(2368, 2368), MED2 = c(2344, -4), 
+                     MED3 = c(-9, -9), MED4 = c(2145, 2145), MED5 = c(-9, -9), 
+                     MED6 = c(-9, -9), MED7 = c(8765, 8765), MED8 = c(2345, 2345)), 
+                row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
> 
> df$total = rowSums(df > 0) # positives 
> df
  MED1 MED2 MED3 MED4 MED5 MED6 MED7 MED8 total
1 2368 2344   -9 2145   -9   -9 8765 2345     5
2 2368   -4   -9 2145   -9   -9 8765 2345     4
```

If it's about the sum of positive values per row

```r
> df$pos_rowsum = 
+   apply(df, 1L, \(x) sum(x[x > 0]))
> df
  MED1 MED2 MED3 MED4 MED5 MED6 MED7 MED8 pos_rowsum
1 2368 2344   -9 2145   -9   -9 8765 2345      17967
2 2368   -4   -9 2145   -9   -9 8765 2345      15623
```

If you want to *replace* all negative values with `0` simply do

```r
> df[df < 0] = 0
> df
  MED1 MED2 MED3 MED4 MED5 MED6 MED7 MED8
1 2368 2344    0 2145    0    0 8765 2345
2 2368    0    0 2145    0    0 8765 2345
```

If it's just about `-9`, do `df[df == -9] = 0` instead.
This operation is not necessary to perform the above mentioned computations as those ignore negative values.

If there are more columns and we only want to select those containing `MED` followed by one or two digits, we can do:

```r
df$total = rowSums(df[grep("^MED\\d{1,2}$", colnames(df))] > 0)
df$pos_rowsum = apply(df[grep("^MED\\d{1,2}$", colnames(df))], 1L, \(x) sum(x[x > 0]))
```

and

```r
df[grep("^MED\\d{1,2}$", colnames(df))][df[grep("^MED\\d{1,2}$", colnames(df))] < 0] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Friede. As added above on the structure of the data, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way so that I do not have to make changes to each column and then carry out the row sums function

Comment: The suggested approach does not make changes on the data.

Comment: Thanks. in your above explanation you have made a data frame from scratch right. My actual data contains 30 rows of MED1-MED30 and total has around 26000 entries in each column. I was confused how would I write a code to achieve the same objective as above with these conditions. My dataset is called 2007d

Comment: Of course, as you do not provide toy data. *30 rows of MED1-MED30*? You propably mean columns? 260k times 30, that doesn't make a difference at all. `2007d` or `df` doesn't really matter how it's named.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I meant 30 columns. My dataset in total contains around 430 variables (columns) and I want to just choose these 30 and make the total column. How do I modify the command as you had inputed to ensure that it only considers the 30 columns (not all columns) and calculates the necessary info

Comment: That is easy as well. It is unkind not to comply with the request to provide sample data.